# How to test failed payment in Google Pay test environment?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, google-pay

I am testing Google pay for android. I got few test cards in my Google account for payment. They are working fine for any successful payments. But I am not getting any way to fail that payment. I want to check failed response whether it could be insufficient fund or anything else. I am using Stripe as payment gateway. How to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, if using pure Google Pay. In general you could add one of Stripe's failing test cards(https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) to your Chrome saved cards(chrome://settings/payments) , if you're using Stripe's PaymentRequestButton they should show up there and you can test that way.

Answer (score 1):

Google Pay (the button and the payment sheet) won't actually process the payment<sup>1</sup> so therefore you won't *generally* receive insufficient funds from Google Pay. It returns a payment credential that you could use to process the payment with Stripe where Stripe may return a response indicating that there are insufficient funds.

I mention *generally* because Google Pay does expose an API that will allow you to check for sufficient funds by performing an authorization with your PSP. This is the [`onPaymentAuthorized`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#onPaymentAuthorized) callback method. The primary difference between checking in this method versus after you receive a response from Google Pay is that the payment sheet is still active and you can ask the user to choose a different payment method.

<sup>1</sup> Google Pay may perform an authorization against the card to check to see if it is active when you add it to your account.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Pay API now supports [test cards from your PSPs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite#gateway-test-cards). Add configuration for your payment gateway under the `tokenizationSpecification` parameter, when you use Google Pay in `TEST` mode and you'll be able to complete successful and filed payment flows.